# Is there a way to update a point with Highcharts Boost?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, frontend, visualization, highcharts-boost

I want to update dynamically a point with Highcharts Boost (color, marker etc...).

Usually, without the Boost Library, the following code works :

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', { 'chart options...'});
chart.series[0].data[0].update({ 'do stuff with point here' })
```

Example : [Update Point without Boost](http://jsfiddle.net/yPT73/1/)

But with the Boost Librabry activated, the following array is empty :

```
chart.stockChart.series[0].data
```

I didn't find any informations in the documentation :

Boost Module Doc : [Boost Module](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module)

Is it possible to dynamically update a point with Highcharts Boost ?

Comment: Depending on how dynamic you want to be you could just do `chart.series[0].yData[index] = newValue` for the indexes you want to update, and then do a `chart.redraw(false)`. It probably wont be suitable for rapid updates though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **no**.

You cannot update points in boost module. Boost module modifies the Highcharts logic so that `Point` (https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point) objects are not created and simpler structures are used instead - it enhances the performance.

**Example** of `series[0].points` array while using boost module:

```
0 : {x: 0, clientX: 31, plotX: 31, plotY: 236, i: 0}
1 : {x: 1, clientX: 91, plotX: 91, plotY: 192, i: 1}
2 : {x: 2, clientX: 152, plotX: 152, plotY: 154, i: 2}
3 : {x: 3, clientX: 213, plotX: 213, plotY: 130, i: 3}
```

Similar topic is discussed here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5999